# How to insert records in Parse using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, post, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to implement CRUD functionality using Node JS as a server-side implementation and Parse-API to manage the NoSQL database. Here is code for implementing that. get() is working properly but post() method is not working properly. One more thing, is it possible to apply cascade delete, update using   Parse? How to insert a record in associated tables, like when I created a record for a product that data will be inserted into two tables.

Get() is working.

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();
Parse = require('parse/node');
var AppID = "XXXXXX";
var Masterkey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var serverURL = "http://myserverIP:port/parse";
Parse.initialize(AppID, Masterkey);
Parse.serverURL = serverURL;
var server = app.listen(9000, '127.0.0.1', function (req, res) {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log(`Server running at http://${host}:${port}/`);
});
app.get('/getTest', function (req, res) {
    GetRecord();
});
app.post('/postTest', function (req, res) {
    PostRecord();
    PostRecord1(); //also tried
});
async function GetRecord() {
    const test = Parse.Object.extend("test");
    const query = new Parse.Query(test);
    const results = await query.find();
    console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " test.");
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var object = results[i];
        console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('name'));
    }
}
function PostRecord() {
    var Test = new Parse.Object.extend("test");
    test.set("name", "Hiren Patel");
    test.save()
        .then((test) => {
            alert('New object created with objectId: ' + test.id);
        }, (error) => {
            alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
        });
}
function PostRecord1() {
    var Test = Parse.Object.extend("test");
    var test = new Test();
    test.set("name", "Hiren Patel");
    test.save();
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the case of `Test`.  you declare `Test` with a leading upper case and then try to set `test` with a leading lower case.  You should be able to see an error in the server logs.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? Please, explain the behavior better, providing an error message and stack trace, if possible.